# Kotlin overload on lambdas that return a value VS ones that don't. Java, Groovy works, but Kotlin doesn't

Tags: java, kotlin, groovy, overloading

very new to Kotlin and trying to make some of my API work in Kotlin without changing API much.

I have a method, let's call it `client` that receives a `validation` function. There are two variants of `Validation`. One that only suppose to do a validation, and the other can also return a value. To streamline user experience, in Java, I exposed two variants of the method. And it works as expected as I believe Java distincts between `void` and `Object` (<R>).

When I use my code in Kotlin, it can't distinct between two and I need to provide an explicit cast.

To remove Java from equation, I tried to replicate the situation in Kotlin using functional interfaces:

```kotlin
fun interface KotlinValidator {
    fun validate()
}

fun interface KotlinValidatorWithReturn {
    fun validateAndReturn(): Any
}

fun client(validator: KotlinValidator) {
    println("validator NO return")
    validator.validate()
}

fun client(validatorAndReturn: KotlinValidatorWithReturn): Any {
    println("validator WITH return")
    return validatorAndReturn.validateAndReturn()
}

fun test() {
    val fromValidator = client {
        100
    }

    val fromValidatorForced = client(KotlinValidatorWithReturn {
        100
    })

    client {
    }
}
```

it prints

```
validator NO return
validator WITH return
validator NO return
```

Based on my googling, it seems to be not possible to make it work without an explicit cast. However I hope that I am wrong as Groovy and Java let me do it.

To provide more context, I am trying to make [WebTau](https://github.com/testingisdocumenting/webtau) HTTP module work nicely with Kotlin.

In Java and Groovy version I can do:

```java
int id = http.post("/customers", customerPayload, ((header, body) -> {
    return body.get("id"); 
}));

http.put("/customers/" + id, changedCustomerPayload, ((header, body) -> {
    body.get("firstName").should(equal("FN"));
    body.get("lastName").should(equal(changedLastName));
}));
```

In Groovy:

```
def id = http.post("/customers", customerPayload) {
    body.id 
}
```

But in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val id: Int = http.post("/customers", customerPayload, HttpResponseValidatorWithReturn { _, body ->
    body.get("id")
})
```

The reason I brought this example is at the moment I am reluctant to change API and rename functions to distinct between the ones that return a value and the ones that don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that in Kotlin, *everything* returns -- they may just return `Unit`.  There is no `void`.

On the other hand, this may mean there is no need to distinguish between these types, you can just have the "with return" version.

Comment: Thank makes sense to have only with return variants in Kotlin. If I remove the return variants then Java users will have to always return null. Is there a way to hide implementations from Kotlin?

Comment: Sure, you can mark them with `@kotlin.Deprecated(DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN)` if you have a dependency on the Kotlin stdlib.

Comment: Any chance to do this from outside module? Want to keep java module as clean as possible

Comment: Now I am thinking to do a Kotlin specific ‘http’ instance and have there only one variant that is with return. So Kotlin users will have to follow a different Import path